# Why aren't a layer's serviceProperties exposed if the data source is broken?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcpy

In ArcObjects you can get the service properties of a map layer by looking at its [`IWorkspaceName.ConnectionProperties`](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/ConnectionProperties_Property/002500000mp2000000/) property set, even if the layer is currently invalid due to a broken connection.

Why are these properties not exposed through [`arcpy.mapping`](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00s300000032000000)'s [`Layer.serviceProperties`](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Layer/00s300000008000000/) dictionary if the layer's data source is broken? <strike>Is this any different in 10.1 (I am using 10.0 SP5 at the moment)?</strike> Just tested at 10.1 SP1, it's the same story.

This [ESRI forum post](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/49260-Determine-Broken-SDE-Connections?p=169297&viewfull=1#post169297) states that they are not exposed, but not the reason it was implemented this way or whether it is going to be improved.